# Studying for a java comeptition

Tags: java

I'm studying for a competition and my study guide has this code:

```
char[] list=new char[5];
        list[1] = '1';
        list[2] = '2';
        list[3] = 3;
        list[4] = 4;

        System.out.println(list[0] + list[1] + list[2] + list[3] + list[4]);
```

The output is 106 but I have no idea how it got that. I thought it was 10. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: `list[3] = 3;` is the ASCII representation not the actual number.

Comment: It's because it's adding the charecter value in code, not the numbers it's filled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, know that `'n' != n`.  That means that the numeric value of a `char` doesn't equal the `char` itself.  The numeric value of a `char` is its Unicode value.  The digits `'0'`-`'9'` are at Unicode code points 48-57, respectively.  Digit *n* is at code point `n + 48`.

You didn't initialize the first `char` of the array, `list[0]`, so it has the initial value of the null character, Unicode point `0`.

2 chars = 48 * 2, plus 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 96 + 10 = 106.

Comment: Awesome. That makes sense. Thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score 1):

The key is that the values in list[1] and list[2] are the *character literals* '1' and '2' which are encoded as their ASCII values, 49 and 50 respectively. The other two are the characters with ASCII values 3 and 4 (both of which are control characters)

In Java, when you add numbers that are not `float`s, `double`s or `long`s, the arguments are promoted to `int`s. Therefore adding the `char`s '1' + '2' + 3 + 4 is the same as adding the `int`s 49 + 50 + 3 + 4, which is the `int` 106.

If you cast the result of the addition as a character

```
System.out.println((char) (list[0] + list[1] + list[2] + list[3] + list[4]));
```

The result would be 'j', the ASCII character for 106.

Comment: but list[0] haven't been initialized, why are you so sure it has a zero value??

Comment: Java automatically initializes arrays to `0`, `false`, or `null`